# Create JSON report from multi-join query in Rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I am trying to create a custom controller action (something like "report") that I can be used to fetch JSON data for some charts. Given that the core of the data is in the what I'll refer to as the `Table1` controller, that’s where I put the method. (I also tried moving it to the `Table2` controller, and creating a whole new `Report` controller, with all bad results.) The problem I’m having is getting it to render JSON. To simplify things, I reduced my method down to just the following:

```
def report
    @table1 = Table1.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @table1}
    end
end
```

Navigating to either `/report` or `/report.json` complains that `The action 'report' could not be found for Table1Controller`. Just creating the file `app/views/table1/report.html.erb` is enough for that message to go away for the former. As for the latter, it now complains of not having a template.  Interestingly, I can create a `report.json.erb` file in the same directory, and the error will go way, but no JSON data.

What's more interesting, is I did the same thing in the a different controller and it works fine. =/

The above is just part one of my issue. I have several related tables and would like to pull specific information that requires several joins. I can write the query, but I can't seem to get Rails to work with me on either point. I'm thinking that there is a "Rails" way of doing this, that I'm just not doing, and is the reason for my woes. Below is the query:

```
select
    table4.name as "Collection",
    count(table4.name) as "Totals"
from
    table1 
left join 
    table2 on table1.table2_id = table2.id
left join 
    table3 on table1.table3_id = table3.id
left join 
    table4 on table3.table4_id = table4.id
left join 
    table5 on table1.table5_id = table5.id
group by table4.name
order by "Totals" desc
```

I tried adding several permutations of routes. I also tried adding a member route as below:

```
resources :table1 do
  member do
    get 'report'
  end
end
```

The resulting route is `/table1/:id/report(.:format)`. This at least claims that it couldn't find the "report" action. All the others just complained about the "show" action.

Comment: You probably don't have a route for it. Learn about and then use 'rake routes'

Comment: I did try adding a route that looked like `get 'report', to: 'table1#report'`. Also tried several placements in the file, both before and after the `resources :table1`

Comment: for the first part are you actually calling it with a json call or testing it by putting the '/report' url in the browser?

Comment: for the second part I would just use Table4.find_by_sql("") and just add in your sql query.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom. Yes. I am appending the '.json' to the end when requesting json response. It complains of not having a template when I try. Adding a file `report.json.erb` to the respective directory avoids the error, but I get no JSON data. As for the query part, I was thinking that approach would be easiest, but didn't know if there was a "Rails" way that would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but I was able to get this to work by moving everything over to another controller. /shrug.